# where can i download ubuntu 14.04.1 lts server?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, software-installation, google-chrome

I am trying to install 14.04.1 version I am getting software installation failed error.where can I find this version in google

Comment: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/

Comment: Why that version specifically? The current 14.04.5 is available for download from the usual places.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple server images for download at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/, depending on your platform.